# How to recursively use LINQ WHERE?

Tags: c#, linq, recursion

I have a method that needs to be recursive, but I am still wrapping my head around LINQ and the WHERE clause.

The objective is to identify the Group Object that holds the passed in String.

GroupGroup and GroupDecision are my derived class while Group is my base, abstract class.

GrouGroup will hold a List property of type Group (base abstract) and GroupDecision has a List property of Strings. I want to use this List property to find which GroupDecision holds the passed in argument. The algorithm works fine, but needs to handle recursion and right now, it is only 1 layer deep.

This is how it looks right now:

```
   private GroupDecision GetParentGroupObject(string Source)
    {
        GroupDecision parentObject = null;
        scenario.TopLevelGroup.Groups.ToList().ForEach(c =>
        {
            if (c is GroupDecision groupDecision)
            {
                if (ParentObjectHelper(groupDecision, Source))
                    parentObject = groupDecision;
            }
            else if (c is GroupGroup groupGroup)
            {
                groupGroup.Groups.ToList().ForEach(x =>
                {
                    if (x is GroupDecision subDecision)
                    {
                        if (ParentObjectHelper(subDecision, Source))
                            parentObject = subDecision;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return parentObject;
    }


private bool ParentObjectHelper(GroupDecision Decision, string Element)
    {
        return Decision.Decisions.Where(c => c == Element).Any();
    }
```

So, again, the method works for 1 level, but I would need it to handle N levels but I am having trouble calling the method recursively because I can't actually access the variables in the Where clause in the Helper method.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where the algorithm needs to "go deeper". Can you add the object definitions so I can understand the object relationships better?

Comment: GroupGroups hold List of Groups, which could be another GroupGroup. I need to get all of the GroupDecisions in all of the GroupGroups Groups and see if the String passed in is contained in the List of Decisions and then return it.

Comment: Ah, now I understand where the recursion is needed. Thank you.

Comment: GetParentGroupObject must call GetParentGroupObject.  Why are you return from ParentObjectHelper()  method just a bool (you have Any()) instead of the entire List?

Comment: You should *really* be using `foreach` to iterate through a sequence.  What you're doing is dramatically slower, uses dramatically more memory, and complicates your code by quite a lot.  It's just all downside.

Answer (score 0):

So first, rather than try and bake the code to traverse a tree into every individual operation that requires it, it's better to just write a generic operation once and re-use that:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Traverse<T>(T root, 
    Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childSelector)
{
    var stack = new Stack<T>();
    stack.Push(root);

    while (stack.Any())
    {
        var next = stack.Pop();
        yield return next;
        foreach (var child in childSelector(next))
            stack.Push(child);
    }
}
```

Your code is also simplified greatly if you make the base class/interface that your classes implement have a `Groups` property, rather than only having one of the sub-classes having that member.  Types that don't have any children can simply return an empty collection.  This means that any code with a collection of these types doesn't need to constantly check the derived types of each item, and can act on the interface alone.  It means that the child selector for the above method becomes just accessing that property of the item.

With that done you can write:

```
private GroupDecision GetParentGroupObject(string source)
{
    return scenario.TopLevelGroup.Groups.Traverse(group => group.Groups)
        .OfType<GroupDecision>()
        .FirstOrDefault(decisionGroup => decisionGroup.Decisions.Any(decision => decision == source);
}
```

Comment: It makes sense, but are these different method signatures in the declaration and the call?

Comment: @Cuphead What do you mean?  The first method is called by the second, the second method has an identical signature to your version.  What different method signature are you worried about?

Comment: I just mean in the return for GetParentObject(). The Traverse parameters are the same for the declaration as they are in using them?

Comment: @Cuphead Yes, they're the same.

Comment: So since this is a static method, I could theoretically just do a return of the static call, right? I am just walking through it but  I am getting 'There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'childSelector' of Group.Traverse<T>(T, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>();

Comment: @Cuphead The error is telling you that you've only provided one of the two needed arguments.

Comment: If Groups is a List property, how does it access the Traverse method even?

Comment: @Cuphead Because traverse is an extension method.

Comment: Is there only one parameter used in the call? I don't see the comma. I might have to try another approach. Thank you, tho.

Comment: @Cuphead There's an implicit parameter of the ienumerable, and an explicit parameter of the lambda.  If you call it like a normal static method, you'll need to pass the implicit parameter explicitly.

Comment: Gotchya. I figured it out. I voted up for your answer. Thank you.